# Can't get TreeView Icons and IconButton for Tests

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, testing-library

I'm trying to test a component that has an `endAdornment` `IconButton` and other with a `TreeView`, but neither the `IconButton` and the `ExpandIcon`/`CollapseIcon` have good options to dispatch test events.

This is the `TextField` component that I'm using:

```js
<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Label"
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="text"
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment >
          <IconButton onClick={openAssetHierarchy}>
            <Folder />
          </IconButton>
        </InputAdornment>
      ),
    }}
/>
```

This is the `TreeView` component:

```js
<TreeView
  defaultCollapseIcon={<ArrowDropDown />}
  defaultExpandIcon={<ArrowRight />}
  defaultEndIcon={<div style={{ width: 24 }} />}
  onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
  onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
>
  [...]
</TreeView>
```

For the `TextField` icon button:
[image: textField icon button]

For `TreeView` when using Testing Playground to get the icon
[image: treeView icon test]

There aren't good queries to get the icons for tests. How can I get these options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the `IconButton` you can add an `aria-label` attribute to the element, then use `getByLabelText` to access it in your test. This is also useful and recommended for accessibility purposes.

```js
<IconButton aria-label="add a file" onClick={openAssetHierarchy}>
    <Folder />
</IconButton>
```

```
screen.getByLabelText('add a file') // Gets you the `IconButton`
```

---

For the `TreeView` items, I assume you don't actually need to access the icon specifically but simply need to access the `TreeItem` for testing purposes. This can be done with `getByRole` and passing the tree item's name.

```js
screen.getByRole('treeitem', { name: /Test1/ }) // Gets you the first `TreeItem`
```

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves! For treeview I did to open the treeitem children only when click in the expandable icon and select the item when clicking on treeitem. To test, I'd like to expand the treeitem, because that I believe I need the icon

Comment: Expanding should work by clicking anywhere on the `TreeItem`, doesn't have to be the icon.

Comment: Yes, by core it works clicking in `TreeItem` but for my use case I have changed to expand/collapse only by clicking on icon and select the item by clicking in Label. I'm using treeview in a Dialog, when choose the `treeitem` my component closes the `Dialog` and return the selected value.